# Identifying a function when reading in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, function

I'm having trouble idetifying what this does? my confusion relates to the "end for" does this mean the function would end the 'for' loop if the value is false?

example data in Array can [2,4,5] Val 3, Result would be false and end the loop or?

Thanks in advance.

```
Function YetToName (data As Integer(), val As Integer) As Boolean    
    Dim i As Integer

        For i = 0 To data.Length - 1    
            If data(i) = val Then    
                Return True    
            End If    
        End For

    Return False    
End Function
```

Comment: If you have this code in your IDE, does it not give you a syntax error on the `End For`?

Answer (score 0):

The code snippet you have provided is not valid vb.net code.

"Exit For" is used to break out of a For-Next loop before the loop completes.

A For-Next Loop must, by definition, have a "Next" statement to be valid.  The code could be rewritten as...

```
Function YetToName(data As Integer(), val As Integer) As Boolean
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim ReturnValue As Boolean = False
    For i = 0 To data.Length - 1
        If data(i) = val Then
            ReturnValue = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    Return ReturnValue
End Function
```